# UrlRewriteFilter Is Not Taking Effect in Tomcat

Tags: jsp, tomcat, http-status-code-404, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

My web is hosted in Centos under Tomcat.
The web worked fine. (no web.xml in WEB-INF)

I wanted to make a permalink for jsp pages using urlrewritefilter-4.0.4.jar
But after upload, the address web.com/COVID-19 showed 404.

This is my web.xml (Default)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <filter>
        <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

This is my urlrewrite.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE urlrewrite PUBLIC "-//tuckey.org//DTD UrlRewrite 4.0//EN" "http://www.tuckey.org/res/dtds/urlrewrite4.0.dtd">
<urlrewrite>
    <rule>
        <from>/COVID-19</from>
        <to>/covid19.jsp</to>
    </rule>
</urlrewrite>
```

Please help, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So, when I am taking a dump contemplating late in the midnight after struggling hours and hours into desperation, I was enlightened.

The reason that urlrewritefilter didn't work was because Tomcat really had nothing to response to.
It was the Apache, it only forwarded url to Tomcat which ended in *.jsp and servlet (mod_jk).
So it's only natural Tomcat didn't get any url ended with "COVID-19" as it was handled by Apache.

I modified the config, and now it's running smooth.
Thank God.